# PHP - Regular Expression - Arrays - Find the last number and add them together

Tags: php, regex, arrays, file

I was given a file that contains something similar to this kind of structure:

```
12345    ABC  100M 001   2.0  ABC    1010  4510  A01 451  Apple, Johnny A  150

12345    ABC  100M 011   2.0  ABC    1010  4510  A01 451  Apple, Johnny A  80

12345    ABC  100 011   2.0  ABC    1010  4510  A01 451  Apple, Johnny A  80
```

I need to grab the following sections from this file:

- Group together the third column (ie. 100M) if they are similar
- Add together the fourth column (if they are in the same group as the third column)
- Add up the last column depending on the fourth column

I've managed to do the following:

```
$List1 = array();
$grab = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("Can't open file");
$check = fgets($grab);

 while(!feof($grab)) {    
   if (ereg("^[[:digit:]]{5} +ABC +([[:digit:]]{3}[[:alpha:]]?)+ ([[:digit:]]{3})",
     $check, $output)) {
  if (!in_array($output[1], $List1)) {      
    array_push($List1, $output[1]);               
  } 
      if (!in_array($output[2], $List1)) {        
    array_push($List1, $output[2]);                    
  } 
}    
$check = fgets($grab);
 }     
 fclose($grab); 

foreach ($List1 as $list) {
   print "$list <br/>";     
 }
```

I have managed to somehow group together the third column.
The fourth column is being displayed, but I'm not sure how to group it together into the third column if it's under the same group.
And I'm not sure how to easily grab the last bit in the file/array. 
Is there a shortcut to getting the last in a file and adding them up?

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help me.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do this. I would recommend that you dump the data to mysql and query it there.

Comment: This is actually a problem that seems SO EASY to solve using SQL. Can you have it in a SQL queryable format? Heh.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$string = '12345    ABC  100M 001   2.0  ABC    1010  4510  A01 451  Apple, Johnny A  150

12345    ABC  100M 011   2.0  ABC    1010  4510  A01 451  Apple, Johnny A  80

12345    ABC  100 011   2.0  ABC    1010  4510  A01 451  Apple, Johnny A  80';

$third = array();
$fourth = array();

foreach (explode("\n", $string) as $line)
{
    // Skip empty lines.
    if (empty($line))
        continue;

    // Clean up any excessive white space.
    $line = trim(preg_replace('~[\s]{2,}~', ' ', $line));

    $info = explode(' ', $line);

    if (!isset($third[$info[2]]))
        $third[$info[2]] = array();

    $third[$info[2]][] = $info;

    if (!isset($fourth[$info[3]]))
        $fourth[$info[3]] = 0;

    $fourth[$info[3]] += (int) end($info);
}

print_r(array(
    'third' => $third,
    'fourth' => $fourth,
));
```

Comment: I tried to attempt the above, but it only returned blank arrays on my end. when I tried to use it with the ' $handle = fopen("cis_enroll.txt", "r") or die("Can't open file");'